# Manage Similar Models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider a `Blog` Project. I have a very similar model named `Blog` and `BlogRequest`. I want to allow individuals to request to publish their content in my blog. `BlogRequest` has entry of all blogs which has been requested by people. A requested Blog must go through a number of stages before they are accepted and published.

BlogRequest Model looks like the following:

```
class BlogRequest(models.Model):
    text = ... # TextField
    author = ... # who created the blog
    created = ... # date created
    modified = ... # date modified

    # some other fields


    stage = ... # choicefield
```

`BlogRequest.stage` field can take many values like `created, edited, formated, reviewed, accepted, rejected` etc. A `BlogRequest` instance goes through a number of stages before being `accepted`.

I now require all the accepted `BlogRequest` instance as an instance of `Blog` Model. Blog model should be a subset of `BlogRequest` and can also contain some extra fields such as `liked_by`,  `disliked_by`and `comments` etc.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    text = ... # TextField
    author = ... # who created the blog
    created = ... # date created
    modified = ... # date modified   

    comments = ... # comments
    liked_by = ... # ManyToManyField
    disliked_by = ... # ManyToManyField

    # some other fields
```

This situation can be handled by creating a Blog instance every time a `BlogRequest` object achieves `accepted` status (signals can help here). Extra details required for a Blog Model can be added afterwards, through admin or using forms outside admin.

This approach has disadvantages such as (say) changing maximum length of blog content will require me changing fields in both the models. (Edited: Say I for some reasons do not want blogs more than 2000 words, I will have to make necessary changes in both models.) Therefore, I want to know if there are better approaches to handle similar situations.

Comment: You talk about a `BlogRequest` model but post a snippet with a `Blog` model, and it's not even clear from your question what a `Blog` or `BlogRequest` are supposed to be (I can hardly make sense of "# some usual blog fields" and even less of "changing maximum length of blog content").

Comment: You can use class inheritance to reuse code for similar models. Check out the django documentation about abstract base classes and proxy models: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's no one-size-fits-all answer here, it mostly depends on details of your workflow.

If a `Blog` (actually a `Post` - a blog is a collection of posts...) is supposed to remain forever unchanged once accepted, a single model (for storage) and [two proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) (one for requests and the other for accepted posts) should work. You could even actually dispense with the proxy models but separating the logic in two distinct classes will make the code easier to work with.

Now if a `Blog` can be updated once accepted and then has to go through the whole validation workflow (while the originally accepted version stays published), you'd be better using two distinct models (with `Blog` having a ForeignKey on `BlogRequest` so you can relate them). You can then avoid the repetition (common fields) by [using an abstract base model class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Answer (score 0):

One better approach to handle this situation is the following.

If you go through any blog tutorial by Django you will find that the `Blog` model has a field called `publish`. The default value for that is always `false`, unless the blog is allowed to be seen by public, in which case it is `true`.

In your case you should remove the `BlogRequest` model completely and just use `Blog` model. And your logic should only show blogs whose stage is `accepted`.

Otherwise the drawback that you've pointed out is going to be very disturbing once your blog has many number of posts. If that is not a solution you can always create a view which will set the stage to `accepted` and then create a Blog post by copying the entire content of BlogRequest model for that particular blog.